# Unable to remove the exact string from text with python re.sub

Tags: python

I have Following text:

```
{
'inputbuffer': 'x06x00x00x00ExplorerStartMenuReadyx00',  
'devicehandle': '0x0000033c', 
'controlcode': 2228388, 
'outputbuffer': 'Ŝx1b3Ϝx83)蝸11\x84ط°\x022��Ѕ\x01A\x81wM\x9c4ø_-1@:b3.Ϝx#8?3)蝸11\x84ط°\x022\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', 
'function': 'openfile' 
}
```

I wanna replace the following part:

```
'inputbuffer': 'x06x00x00x00ExplorerStartMenuReadyx00'
```

with

```
'inputbuffer':
```

and

```
'outputbuffer': 'Ŝx1b3Ϝx83)蝸11\x84ط°\x022��Ѕ\x01A\x81wM\x9c4ø_-1@:b3.Ϝx#8?3)蝸11\x84ط°\x022\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

with

```
'outputbuffer':
```

I have wrote following python code:

```
import codecs
import base64
x1="{'inputbuffer': 'x06x00x00x00ExplorerStartMenuReadyx00',  'devicehandle': '0x0000033c', 'controlcode': 2228388, 'outputbuffer': 'Ŝx1b3Ϝx83)蝸11\x84ط°\x022��Ѕ\x01A\x81wM\x9c4ø_-1@:b3.Ϝx#8?3)蝸11\x84ط°\x022\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', 'function': 'openfile' }"
x3=re.sub(r'(^\w+)','',x1)
x4=re.sub(r'(\<|>)','',x3)
x5=re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+','', x4)
x6=re.sub(r'(\$|%|\|\(|\)|\\|@|\.|_|-|#|\?)','',x5)
x9=re.sub(r'\'outputbuffer\':\s\'.*\'','\'outputbuffer\':',x6, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
x10=re.sub(r'\'inputbuffer\':\s\'.*\',\s','\'inputbuffer\':',x9, flags=re.MULTILINE)
print(x10)
```

the desired output should replace only these two parts and keep the others intact as following:

```
{'inputbuffer':,  'devicehandle': '0x0000033c', 'controlcode': 2228388, 'outputbuffer': }
```

but what I get is :

```
{'inputbuffer':'controlcode': 2228388, 'outputbuffer': }
```

which removes some parts that should remain in the resulting text.

I would be so grateful if somebody help me to figure out what is wrong with this code.

Comment: Why would you want to turn a fine json response string into I-don't-know-what-it-is....? :(

Comment: where `json`-like text cames from?

Comment: it is a part of csv file and the csv file was extracted from json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont convert your json to text you could achieve your target very easily. just use this code

```
x1 = {'inputbuffer': 'x06x00x00x00ExplorerStartMenuReadyx00',  'devicehandle': '0x0000033c', 'controlcode': 2228388, 'outputbuffer': 'Ŝx1b3Ϝx83)蝸11\x84ط°\x022��Ѕ\x01A\x81wM\x9c4ø_-1@:b3.Ϝx#8?3)蝸11\x84ط°\x022\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00', 'function': 'openfile' }
x1[inputbuffer] = ""
x2[outputbuffer] = ""
print(x1)
```